# Need to prevent mousehover over click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have the following code:

```
$('img').on("mouseenter",function(){
        //show overlay
    });

$("#overlay").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        //hide overlay  
})
```

When i click on the overlay, it should close. But when i happen to be over an image it does not close.I receive both mouseclick and mouseenter events
How do i prevent this?

I am using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: could u provide a fiddle .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6SZQB/

Comment: Good God! It works on chrome!!! it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: The fiddle does not work in firefox as well

Comment: Lowering the `z-index` of `img` ( as compared to overlay ) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on image, it first goes in **click** event then **mouseenter** event. So, click event hides then mouseenter shows again. So, you can not hide layout when you are on the img. But, **if you disable mouseenter event of img in a short duration, the problem will be solved in Chrome and FF**.

As in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SZQB/12/) change your js function as :

```
$(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();      

    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

    $("#overlay")
    .height(docHeight)
    .css({
        'opacity' : 0.4,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background-color': 'black',
        'width': '100%',
        'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
        'background-attachment':'fixed',
        'background-position':'center',
        'z-index': 5000
    }).on("click",function(e) {   
               hideOverlay();  
               unbindImgMouseEnter();
               setTimeout(bindImgMouseEnter, 100); 
        }).hide();       

    bindImgMouseEnter();   
});

function bindImgMouseEnter(){
    $('img').on("mouseenter", showOverlay);
}

function unbindImgMouseEnter(){
    $('img').off("mouseenter");
}

function showOverlay(){   
    $("#overlay").show(); 

    console.log('showed');
}

function hideOverlay(){
    $("#overlay").hide(); 

    console.log('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thank this seems to work!Although i dont understand why preventDefault  did not work

Comment: But there is a bug, after closing overlay outside image, entering img doesn't work once. Trying to solve.

Comment: hi serefbilge, i just figured that if you click the overlay when on the image and move the mouse, the overlay is shown again

Comment: I tried again, it works correctly. It doesn't show up except mouseenter. Try again carefully. http://jsfiddle.net/6SZQB/7/

Comment: Will it make a difference on different browsers as it doesn't work proper on FF

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault not checking in all browsers. If you make timeout 100 it works on ff and chrome but not it ie. Let me look again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `mouseenter` event, when you click the overlay.

```
$("#overlay").on("click",function(event) {
   $('img').off("mouseenter");   // Remove the mouseenter event handler
    event.preventDefault();
        //hide overlay  
});
```

**Suggestion:** better use `.hover` instead of `mouseenter`

```
$('img').on("hover",function(){
        //show overlay
    });

$("#overlay").on("click",function(event) {
    $('img').off('hover');
    event.preventDefault();
        //hide overlay  
})
```

Comment: This would remove the mouseenter event completely.I need to keep the event for other images as well

Comment: Also i need to show the overlay only when i move the mouse over any image

Comment: using the fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/6SZQB/2/) in FF works but now i need to click twice to close it

Comment: it appears the mouse over event gets called after click event.Any idea why this could be happening?